# Overriding editTextStyle doesn't work with latest Material Components base style

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

In an app of mine, I'm using the `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` as a base style. In this style, which I call `AppTheme`, I'm trying to override `editTextStyle` to provide a custom style for `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` (according to the source code, it uses `R.attr.editTextStyle` as a default style).

This is my current theme, related to the TIEditText and TILayout:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    [ primary and secondary colors, OnColors, etc.]
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextInputEditText</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout</item>

    [ Custom attribute for testing, defined in attrs.xml ]
    <item name="textInputEditTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextInputEditText</item>
</style>
```

For some reason, even though I set `editTextStyle`, if I use it in code, it does not get applied:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tilFirstName"
    style="?attr/textInputStyle"
    android:hint="@string/label_firstname"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        style="?attr/editTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@={viewModel.firstName}" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

However if I replace the style of `firstName` with `?attr/textInputEditTextStyle`, it works.

Why can't I override `editTextStyle` in the default theme? What the hell is going on?

Target SDK is 28, minSDK is 21, Material library version is `1.1.0-alpha06`

Comment: The same problem for me. Wasted a lot of time and still don't get why this attribute is not applied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For some reason, even though I set editTextStyle, if I use it in code, it does not get applied

It happens because the default styles of the `TextInputLayout` override the **`editTextStyle`** using the `materialThemeOverlay` attribute.

For example the `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox` has this default style:

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox" parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">
       @style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox
    </item>
    ....
</style>
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you choose override MaterialComponents style instead of add a custom default definition? :) I'm trying to apply it but I don't understand why it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @JosselinePerdomo It is the default style provided by the Material Components for the `TextInputLayout.FilledBox`. I explained why `style="?attr/editTextStyle"` doesn't work. It is a default attribute defined at app theme level. It is overridden by the components itself (it uses the same `attr` overridden with the `materialThemeOverlay`). Instead `textInputEditTextStyle` works because it is a custom attribute not overridden.

Answer (score 35):

Let's just move past the part where we all recognize that Android themes and styles are singularly the most absurd wasteland of hackery and guesswork ever devised by human beings.

This is an expansion on the previous answer.  Same silly 'hack'.  I was able to style the `TextInputEditText` by setting `editTextStyle`, but not where it intuitively belongs, but rather inside a custom `materialThemeOverlay` nested within the style defined for `textInputStyle`.  Witness:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- works fine -->
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayoutStyle</item>
    <!-- should work fine, doesn't work, happily ignored -->
    <!-- <item name="editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextInputEditTextStyle</item> -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <!-- other props (boxBackgroundMode, boxBackgroundColor, boxStrokeColor, etc) -->
    <!-- can we set editTextStyle from here? Of course not! We should magically know we need a material theme overlay-->
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/AppTheme.MaterialThemeOverlay</item>
</style>

<!-- style inception! a style, child of another style, whose only purpose is to refer to yet another style -->
<style name="AppTheme.MaterialThemeOverlay">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextInputEditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- finally, the style we SHOULD have been able to set from the theme -->
<style name="AppTheme.TextInputEditTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

All of the above ridiculousness and ANOTHER day of my life thrown in the trash, just to change the color of text.  Thaaaaanks Aaaaaandroid.

Comment: Thank you so much ) This was SO confusing before I used your solution. It's just below the understandment for me how all styles are just styles, and this one particular is themeOverlayed style

Comment: This is just ridiculous, Google. They really need to re-vamp their entire theming system. Thank you for saving me even more countless hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Currently in the middle of rebranding our app and I couldn't agree more with the first sentence. Take my upvote!